# high resolution heatmap in r

Tags: r, heatmap

I used the R listing below and got a very nice `heatmap`:

```
png( "test-8.png", width =800 , height =750 )
heatmap(1-cor(df),distfun=function(x){as.dist(x)},symm=F,Rowv=NULL, Colv=NULL)
dev.off()
```

But it was produced with quite low resolution. After google search i've found possible solution:

```
png( "test-8.png", width =800 , height =750,res=600 )
heatmap(1-cor(df),distfun=function(x){as.dist(x)},symm=F,Rowv=NULL, Colv=NULL)
dev.off()
```

Unfortunately i got the error message after the code execution:

```
Error in par(op) : invalid value specified for graphical parameter "pin"
Calls: heatmap -> par
Execution halted
```

How i can manage it? Any suggestion will be appreciated.

Comment: It would be nice if you'd make this reproducible though.

Comment: did you try increasing the height and width? I don't know what else you would expect would happen when you shrink an image down to less than 2x2 inches

Comment: @rawr Brilliant! It was exactly the reason.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The settings you have are likely reducing the `pin` size below the minimum allowed value (still looking for documentation on that). Try using the following. You may need to load the `grid` package to get the units argument to work.

```
png("high_res.png", width = 4, height = 4, units = 'in', res = 600)
heatmap(1-cor(df),distfun=function(x){as.dist(x)},symm=F,Rowv=NULL, Colv=NULL)
dev.off()
```

Comment: Your code with small adjustments (i used `width = 6, height = 6`) works perfectly for me.

Answer (score 0):

I was having the same problem and ran the following code,

```
par()
```

There are lots of items displayed. One of them is $pin which has two values. One was negative. I tried the following,

```
par(pin=c(0,0))
```

This seemed to do the trick. I still don't know what this means and why the error occurred.